# "Nested" union types in elm

Tags: types, elm, union-types

I'm learning elm and trying to switch my mindset from TypeScript's type system. I was wondering what's the best way to use nested types like this:

```
type Player = X | O
type Cell = Player | Empty

viewCell: Cell -> string
viewCell cell = 
  case cell of
    X -> "X"
    O -> "O"
    Empty -> " "
```

the compiler complains

```
The first pattern is trying to match `X` values of type:

    Player

But the expression between `case` and `of` is:

    Cell
```

I can change viewCell like so, but then I don't know how to get the player

```
viewCell: Cell -> String
viewCell cell = 
  case cell of
    Player -> -- how to get the player ??
    Empty -> " "
```

The problem is not displaying the values per se, rather "destructuring" the nested union type so to speak. I want to use it later on in something like this:

```
check: (List Cell) -> string
check three =
  case three of
    [X, X, X] -> "X won"
    [O, O, O] -> "O won"
    _ -> "still going"
```

which also gives me similar complaints from the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time a constructor and type can share a name is if you do something like:

`type Tag = Tag String`

Consider that you've said

`type Cell = Player | Empty`

but might also want

`type Winner = Player | None`

So what's `Player`? Is it a `Cell` or a `Winner`? It can't be both.

The simple solution is:

`type Cell = PlayerCell Player | Empty`

`type Winner = WinningPlayer Player | None`

`PlayerCell X` is a cell with player X.  `WinningPlayer O` is a winner.

When destructuring, you can nest:

```
case cell of
  PlayerCell X -> 
    ...
  PlayerCell O -> 
    ...
  Empty -> 
    ...
```

In fact, you can destructure more complex data structures:

```
  case cellRow of 
    [ PlayerCell O, PlayerCell O, PlayerCell O] -> 
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks! So I guess there's no way to "destructure" the type like in my first example? Do you have any book or article recommendations for better understanding elm's type system?

Comment: I think the Beginner Elm Slack is a good place to get quick answers when learning the basics. Added a more complex destructuring to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

In

```
type Cell = Player | Empty
```

`Player` is not a type, but a value of type `Cell`. You could however also give it an argument, in which case it would be a value constructor that when given an argument return a value of type `Cell`. So in

```
type Player = X | O
type Cell = Player Player | Empty
```

the first `Player` in `Player Player` is essentially a function that when given a value of type `Player` will return a value of type `Cell`. Or `Player -> Cell` in type-speak.

Note also that both the type and constructor can have the same name because they're in different domains. They don't conflict because they refer to different things, one referring to the type and the other to the value (constructor). But the fact that you can doesn't necessarily mean you should, since it can be pretty confusing.

You can then pattern match on `Cell` and the nested `Player` like this:

```
type Player = X | O
type Cell = Player Player | Empty

viewCell: Cell -> String
viewCell cell = 
  case cell of
    Player X -> "X"
    Player O -> "O"
    Empty -> " "
```

`Player` and `Empty` here refer to the constructors/variants of `Cell`, not to types. And similarly `X` and `O` refer to the variants of `Player`, which are also not types.